# Problem getting information from the database

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following query

```
function footGames()
{
    global $database;
    $q = "SELECT name FROM ".TBL_GAME." WHERE active = '1' AND type = 'soccer'";
    return mysql_query($q, $database->myConnection);
}
```

The $database->myConnection is the following

```
function myConnection() {
   return $this->connection;
```

}

$database is the class that myConnection is in.

Any ideas why the footGames method isn't working?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myConnection` is a function, you need to call it (note the parentheses):

```
return mysql_query($q, $database->myConnection());
```

Comment: Thanks, I noticed this just after posting and wanted to wait until I had some feedback. Fixed, thanks.